# LightDM does not display on startup?

Tags: lightdm

I've had this issue since the switch to Systemd.

It persists even on 16.10.

When I start the system, LightDM does not show (it is running, but a blinking underscore shows up instead). I have to restart it from a virtual terminal.

How can I fix this? (Reinstalling LightDM doesn't work, and reinstalling the OS is not an option).

The contents of `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log.old`:

```
[+615957.88s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to 
[+615967.48s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c152
[+615976.68s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c151
[+615976.68s] DEBUG: Session c151 is already active
[+615993.68s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c152
[+615998.08s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c151
[+615998.08s] DEBUG: Session c151 is already active
[+616027.63s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c152
[+616036.37s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c151
[+616036.37s] DEBUG: Session c151 is already active
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Unity or Ubuntu-Desktop?

Comment: I upgraded the system last night so naturally those packages got updated as a part of the process. I don't actually use the unity-greeter anyway, so I doubt unity itself would have any bearing on this issue. Also, ubuntu-desktop is a metapackage - it contains no actual files.

Comment: I was thinking of purging and reinstalling them, not updating which may not happen for awhile. It should not effect any of your data.

Comment: But how would that solve an issue with lightdm?

Comment: What do the logs say?